# ¿Cómo resaltar valores en un JTable?

Tags: java

Cómo consigo algo así. ¿Alguna idea?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Deseo resaltar la columna y la fila hasta llegar el lugar seleccionado por el usuario, no debe seleccionarse toda la fila ni toda la columna, solo hasta llegar al punto indicado.
Espero hacerme entender.

Comment: Hola @Julian. Por favor brinda más explicaciones sobre el problema. Una imagen vale más que mil palabras, pero la imagen en este caso también se queda corta para expresar lo que necesitas.

Answer (score -1):

Aquí tienes un ejemplo que dibuja una fila y una columna resaltada en azul. Puedes adaptarlo rápidamente a lo que deseas:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import com.sun.java.swing.*;
import com.sun.java.swing.table.*;

class ejemplo extends JPanel {
  private JTable tabla;
  private JScrollPane panelScroll;
  private String titColumna[];
  private String datoColumna[][];

  public ejemplo() {
    setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
    // Creamos las columnas y las cargamos con los datos que van a
    // aparecer en la pantalla
    CreaColumnas();
    CargaDatos();
    // Creamos una instancia del componente Swing
    tabla = new JTable( datoColumna,titColumna );
    // Aquí se configuran algunos de los parámetros que permite 
    // variar la JTable
    tabla.setShowHorizontalLines( false );
    tabla.setRowSelectionAllowed( true );
    tabla.setColumnSelectionAllowed( true );
    // Cambiamos el color de la zona seleccionada (azul/blanco)
    tabla.setSelectionForeground( Color.white );
    tabla.setSelectionBackground( Color.cyan );
    // Incorporamos la tabla a un panel que incorpora ya una barra
    // de desplazamiento, para que la visibilidad de la tabla sea
    // automática
    panelScroll = new JScrollPane( tabla );
    add( panelScroll, BorderLayout.CENTER );
  }


  // Creamos las etiquetas que sirven de título a cada una de
  // las columnas de la tabla
  public void CreaColumnas() {
    titColumna = new String[8];

    for( int i=0; i < 8; i++ ) {
      titColumna[i] = "Col: "+i;
    }
  }

  // Creamos los datos para cada uno de los elementos de la tabla
  public void CargaDatos() {
    datoColumna = new String[100][8];

    for( int iY=0; iY < 100; iY++ ) {
      for( int iX=0; iX < 8; iX++ ) {
    datoColumna[iY][iX] = "" + iX + "," + iY;
      }
    }
  }


  public static void main( String args[] ) {
    Frame ventana = new JFrame( "Ejemplo JTable" );

    ventana.addWindowListener( new WindowAdapter() {
      public void windowClosing( WindowEvent evt ){
    System.exit( 0 );
      }
    } );
    ventana.getContentPane().add( new ejemplo(),BorderLayout.CENTER );
    ventana.setSize( 300,180 );

    ventana.setVisible( true );
  }
}
```